# How To Break line the Title after a certain character using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<span class="wvpl-product_title " title="" data-id="7164" data-index="0" data-event="">                     
            Amitsa - Luna (San Francisco)           

</span>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT IS:

```
Amitsa
Luna
(San Francisco)
```

Comment: A little more information can be helpful.  Is there something you've tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

match on sequence of word characters or parens enclosed sequence of characters, join with newline.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.wvpl-product_title').forEach(x=>x.innerHTML=x.innerText.match(/\w+|\([^)]+\)/g).join('<br>'))
```

```html
<span class="wvpl-product_title " title="" data-id="7164" data-index="0" data-event="">                     
            Amitsa - Luna (San Francisco)           
</span>

<span class="wvpl-product_title " title="" data-id="7164" data-index="0" data-event="">                     
            Amitsa1 - Luna (San Francisco)           
</span>


<span class="wvpl-product_title " title="" data-id="7164" data-index="0" data-event="">                     
            Amitsa2 - Luna (San Francisco)           
</span>


<span class="wvpl-product_title " title="" data-id="7164" data-index="0" data-event="">                     
            Amitsa3 - Luna (San Francisco)           
</span>

<span class="wvpl-product_title " title="" data-id="7164" data-index="0" data-event="">                     
            Amitsa4 - Luna (San Francisco)           
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. unfortunately the code did not work in my site. I have a hundred of TITLE with that kind of format. everytime I click the TITLE it will load to the footer player with that class ----- class="wvpl-product_title "

Comment: you'll need to provide more details for help.  if you want to break line in HTML you need to insert <br> and not just \n

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I mean,  break line in HTML, I tried your updated code but still doesnt work. I working on woocommerce and have a hundred of MP3 products displayed in PRODUCT TABLE when I click MP3 PLAY BUTTON it will played in the FOOTER PLAYER and displayed the TITLE.

Comment: I can't help with that without seeing the HTML involved